# SSRS How can I prevent my report adding backslashes \ in front of a percentage % sign when my report is run?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, percentage, backslash

I've created a report in which I have several text boxes inserted, with static text added to them.  Some of these text strings contain a percentage % sign.

When running the preview, the text renders correctly, but when I run the report in a live situation, the strings get altered and backslash \ is inserted after every % sign.

How can I prevent the report from doing this?

Comment: are the placeholders set to render as html in the placeholder properties?

Comment: As it's a text box, there's no placeholder in it.  Text box properties don't provide a "Markup Type" section for me to select HTML or None.

I did experiment with inserting a placeholder into the text box, but my SQL / expression knowledge is very basic, so I failed to work out how to enter text into the expression.   You cannot simply paste text into the expression.  A Placeholder does have that HTML option which -might- help, if I can work it out.

Comment: If you just need to left click the field or expression within the text box then right click once it's highlighted. Here's a short GIF to demonstrate. https://imgur.com/a/d5heJB7 You'll need to click the image to see the animated gif

Comment: I’m sorry I think I was unclear. I understand how to access placeholder properties.  However these text boxes simply have text pasted directly into them. This does not create a placeholder within the text box, it simply allows the text to appear and be editable.  As I said above, I also tried inserting a placeholder into the text box instead, then inserting my text into the value of that placeholder, but that alone won’t work - it required a correctly formatted expression to contain the text,  something beyond my simple understanding.

Comment: Every textbox with text in has a placeholder, even if you just type p[lain text into it, once entered that test IS in a placeholder. If you want to add text in as an expression the just use `="my test"`

Comment: Hi Alan,

Thanks for the info.  I've set a placeholder inside the text box and set a value using:

 =" my text goes here " 

in the expression.  This allows me to access and set the HTML Markup Type  - progress!  But on testing the report when the string reaches the percent sign, instead of:

one-off 1% charge

it says

one-off 1\% charge

This does not happen in the preview.  Pesky backslash strikes again :(

Comment: Can you edit your question and show exactly what you have in the textbox/placeholder include anything relevant such as HTML markup setting etc and I will try to reproduce it. It might just need escaping but I can't remember off the top of my head exactly how to do that, it might be `/%` or `%%` but if you share the setup, I can try to reproduce this evening.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll highlight the text from one of my placeholders here in bold:
**="Orders over £5k subject to a one-off 1% charge based on the total order value. This charge will cover all call-off deliveries and storage of your order for up to 6 months."**

P.S. the equals sign is within the bold area, I don't know why it's not being changed though.

Answer (score 0):

The preview in SSRS works perfectly. It’s only when the report is deployed that the backslashes appear.  The deployment is within a custom report viewer built into a client website and the author of the report viewer has updated it to scan for and remove the unwanted backslashes - I wasn’t aware this could be done.  This has fixed the problem.

We have a SQL Report Viewer written as part of our CRM solution which connects to SQL and runs SQL Reports in a webpage.  It was this solution that was introducing the superfluous characters - not Visual Studio.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).